# Animate window with easing

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a Element that will open when I click on a button, it works, but now I need to animate it, and that's what I don't know to do. This is my code:

**jQuery**

```
$(".trigger-window-1").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".window-1").toggleClass("closed-window");
});
```

When I click the element with the class ***".trigger-window-1"*** it opens the the window with the class ***".trigger-window-1"***, pretty simple, but now I want to animate that and I can't figure out how.

PD: I know I must use animate function, but I can't figure out how to. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the animate function on a lot of different data based values such as the height. You can see jQuery's animate function [doc here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Here's an example:

```
$(".trigger-window-1").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".window-1").toggleClass("closed-window");
if($(".window-1").hasClass('closed-window')) {
    $(".window-1").animate({
        'height':100
    });
} else {
    $(".window-1").animate({
        'height':200
    });
}
```

});

[Here a live example of the above on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc81L8us/)